# Hide post parameters on submit in a jsp

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, submit

I have a problem with a post form in JSP. The form parameters are filled by the user and then send using post submit. The problem is that they are vulnerable because everybody can see them.

How can I hide/securize the parameters on the client side before sending them? Is there another option to send these parameters in a more secure way?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can not do it directly,try `SSL` for it

Comment: Use spring security and enable csrf ,corrs for more security.

Comment: Thanks for your proposals but I have permitted only to modify files in client (front) not the server (back). Is this possible in client? Can you include here an example or link to learn how to do it in the way you suggest? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using an https server should be enough, or, more secure, you can use spring security with the crsf token, take a look here https://spring.io/projects/spring-security

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you include some example in client code? Thanks.

Comment: it is done at server side, if you want to use an SSL certificate you have nothing to do with java, just configure your application server to use SSL  https://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/